# Embedding and homologies

Tags: general-topology, algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology, simplicial-complex

Let $X$ be a $2$-complex, embed it in $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n$ and take the epsilon neighbourhood. Denote the boundary of this new manifold as $Y$. Does $Y$ have trivial homologies for dimension $3$ to $n-3$?